# Height not actually changing hieght while floating

Tags: html, css, css-float, clearfix

Right now I'm coding a menu that has a two column layout. This is the code.

HTML:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>replit</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="stockapps">
        <img src="icons/eShop.svg">
        <img src="icons/sverse.svg">
      </div>
      <div class="main">
        <p>
          Hello!
        </p>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```css
    .stockapps {
      background-color: #111;
      float: left;
      width: 5%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .stockapps :after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    .stockapps img{
      width:100%;
      display: inline;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .main {
      float: left;
      padding: 2%;
      width: 91%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

The issue is that the stockapps div tag is not filling the whole screen with height instead opting to only fill the area the children objects take up.

I have tried using the clear-fix and setting overflow to hidden but neither seem to fix the issue. Its likely some beginner mistake as CSS is not my strong suit

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ow8Lc7t6/) showcases the issue.

Comment: your fiddle. is that what you are trying to attain seems like your code doesnt match from here to fiddle. in your fiddle you can use display:flex on your .wrapper see if thats what youa re trying to attain. Im just kind a confuse on what you are trying to attain. Let me know exactly i might be able to help.

Comment: Whoops! My mistake the fiddle listed there is wrong. Its fixed now.

Comment: ok, so your  .stockapps{ width: 5%; } thats not really gonna fit on the whole screen. what are you trying to do with the images?? you want it to fit on the entire div?? an illustration on what you want will help you or just explain better.

Comment: In the code given you seem to be trying to put an after pseudo element on each of the children of stock apps. This may not work as they are imgs but could you describe what you want them to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap stockapps and main divs into a container div

Style this container as below

I used background color for stockapps div to show you its height

```css
.container {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: stretch;
    /*Set height as you want, you can use height in px */
  height: 100vh;
}

.stockapps {
/* used background-color to show you how much height it takes*/
  background-color: #999;
  /*You can ignore width if it's not convenient for your desired final output */
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="stockapps">
    <img src="icons/eShop.svg">
    <img src="icons/sverse.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <p>
      Hello!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That fixed it! Tysm!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to create a 2-column layout for your menu.

To achieve this layout, I would wrap the `<div class="stockapps">` and `<div class="main">` into another `<div>` with class of `manu-wrap` and add this CSS styles:

```
.menu-wrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

I would then remove the `float` properties and you should have a working 2-column layout.

You can find more about `display: flex` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything. This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hmfe5o2n/) showcases the problem.